# How to manually create an App.xaml file in a WPF Python Project in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, ironpython, ironpython-studio

When we  create a new  **WPF C# Project from Visual Studio** we get **4 basic files** `"App.xaml","App.cs","MainWindow.xaml","MainWindow.cs"`

Here `App.xaml` file is basically used for storing `application related Resources` in one file to be present all over the application.

But when creating a  **WPF Python Project in Visual Studio**  we get only **2 files** `"MainWindow.xaml" and "MainWindow.py"`

`I want to create 2 more file in my Python project` **"App.xaml"** and **"App.py"** so that in `"App.xaml"` I can easily define my all application related resources styles and control-templates.

Plz Help!!

Answer (score 6):

You can add an Application file to your project from the Solution Explorer. You can press Alt+S to open it. In the Solution Explorer, select your project and then right click and select the *Add* menu item and then *New Item* menu item from the popup menu.

Next, in the *Add New Item* dialog window, you can select *WPF* from the *Installed Templates* on the left to filter the available templates. Then, you can simply choose to add a *Resource Dictionary* and name it `App.xaml`. As long as you put the relevant code in it, it will be fine:

```
<Application x:Class="ManuallyCreatingAWpfProject.app"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Startup="AppStartup"
    >
  <Application.Resources>

  </Application.Resources>

</Application>

...

public partial class App : Application
{
    void AppStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs args)
    {
        Window1 mainWindow = new Window1();
        mainWindow.Show();
    }
}
```

This code was taken from the [Walkthrough: Manually Creating a Windows Presentation Foundation Project Using Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page on MSDN, which you may also find interesting.

You might also want to go to the project properties (right click on the project in the Solution Explorer and select *Properties*) and set the *Startup Object* to the `App.xaml` file in the *Application* tab. Finally, you'd better set the *Build Action* to *ApplicationDefinition* in the `App.xaml` file properties.